# SkiaSharp DrawText

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I've been searching trough the documentation of SkiaSharp for a way to add text using touch command.
So in order to add text, I have to add the following line:

```
canvas.DrawText(text, x, y, SkPaint)
```

I couldn't find any way to set those `text, x, y` values dynamically (example: get the `text` parameter from Entry, and `x, y` parameters from touch event). How to do it like that, or that is the only way?

I already have code for drawing paths on touch:

```
 case SKTouchAction.Pressed:
                var p = new SKPath();
                p.MoveTo(e.Location);
                temporaryPaths[e.Id] = p;
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Moved:
                if (e.InContact)
                    temporaryPaths[e.Id].MoveTo(e.Location);
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Released:
                paths.Add(temporaryPaths[e.Id]);
                temporaryPaths.Remove(e.Id);
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Cancelled:
                temporaryPaths.Remove(e.Id);
                break;
```

Comment: canvas.DrawText(myEntry.Text, x, y, SkPaint);

Comment: Be careful with drawing text using SkiaSharp if you want to localize your app to different languages. SkiaSharp out of the box does not support scripts with connected letters (like Arabic) or RTL (like Hebrew). You need to apply text shaping (ie harfbuzz) and even then it's not easy.